# Access variable outside try-catch block

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(std::string str);
    std::string GetSomething();
};

int main()
{
    std::string s = "";
    try
    {
        ClassA a = ClassA(s);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        //Do something
        exit(1);
    }

    std::string result = a.GetSomething();

    //Some large amount of code using 'a' out there.
}
```

I would like the last line could access the `a` variable. How could I achieve that, given ClassA doesn't have default constructor `ClassA()` and I would not like to use pointers? Is the only way to add a default constructor to `ClassA`?

Comment: Why not put it in `try` block? If you throw an exception, you will `exit` anyway.

Comment: The question makes no sense: If the construction of `a` throws an exception, `a` is useless anyways.

Comment: `catch` must have stuff after it, e.g. `catch(...)`

Comment: I would not like to put everything later in this try-catch block, there is some code out there so the try would be very large. Additionally there could be exceptions thrown later with same type as the one that could be thworn in the ClassA(std::string) constructor, and I would like to distinguish them.

Comment: If you were just planning to `exit(1)` you may as well just not catch the exception, or let it propagate up to earlier handling

Comment: You can always use an `std::aligned_storage` and placement `new` plus an explicit destructor call to delay a constructor call from object creation. And even it you use it, you will have UB because you will be using an object after a constructor of it throwed.

Comment: The obvious answer is to put your use of "a" inside the try block. If your concern is additional indentation of all your code, you can merge the function body with the try block.

Answer (score 11):

You can't or shouldn't. Instead you could just use it within the `try` block, something like:

```
try
{
    ClassA a = ClassA(s);

    std::string result = a.GetSomething();
}
catch(...)
{
    //Do something
    exit(1);
}
```

The reason is that since `a` goes out of scope after the `try` block referring to the object after that is undefined behavior (if you have a pointer to where it were).

If you're concerned with `a.GetSomething` or the assignment `throw`s you could put a `try-catch` around that:

```
try
{
    ClassA a = ClassA(s);

    try {
        std::string result = a.GetSomething();
    }
    catch(...) {
        // handle exceptions not from the constructor
    }
}
catch(...)
{
    //Do something only for exception from the constructor
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Sometimes that's not the case. If object initialization has to be checked with unique exception handling, additional methods shouldn't be included into a try block. The reason is inability to distinguish the source of exception.

Answer (score 7):

You can use some sort of `optional` or just use `std::unique_ptr`.

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "";
    std::unique_ptr<ClassA> pa;
    try
    {
        pa.reset(new ClassA(s));
    }
    catch
    {
        //Do something
        exit(1);
    }

    ClassA& a = *pa; // safe because of the exit(1) in catch() block
    std::string result = a.GetSomething();

    //Some large amount of code using 'a' out there.
}
```

Comment: Just FYI. This adds unnecessary heap operation which can cause performance degradation in some cases.

Comment: Yeah, in C++17 there is `std::optional` for that.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, just extending the `try` block to include the usage of `a` is the simplest solution.

Also, if you were really planning to `exit(1)` or otherwise abort the program on failure then simply don't put a `try` block here at all. The exception will propagate up, aborting the program if it is not caught .

---

One alternative is to use `std::optional` . This is the same sort of concept as using a pointer, but it uses automatic allocation and so you are less likely to create a memory leak. This is currently *experimental* status; you can use `boost::optional` instead if your compiler doesn't have `std::experimental::optional`:

```
#include <experimental/optional>
using std::experimental::optional;   
using std::experimental::in_place;

// ...

    optional<ClassA> a;

    try 
    {
        a = optional<ClassA>(in_place, s);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
         // display message or something
    }

    std::string result;
    if ( a )
        result = a->GetSomething();
```

I'd like to reiterate though that this is a bit of a spaghetti style and it'd be better to design your code differently so you aren't continually testing whether construction succeeded or failed.

This requires `ClassA` be movable or copyable. The `in_place` is a special argument which invokes a perfect forwarding constructor for the remaining arguments. Without `in_place` you can only give an actual `ClassA` as constructor argument, it doesn't consider implicit conversions to `ClassA`.  (This is how `optional` avoids the ambiguity between copy-construction and list-initialization from object of the same type).